# Having issue while updating a column value of a table using uuid column in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I try to update a column value, with a uuid column in the where clause, I'm getting an error.

```
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I am using spring boot with native query. Here is the native query:

```
 @Query(value = "UPDATE employee " +
            "SET status = :status  where employeeId = :employeeId", nativeQuery = true)
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    void updateROGS(@Param("status") String status, @Param("employeeId") UUID employeeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be worth casting the employeeId to type text for easier comparison and then sending your parameter in as a String?

Something like;

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE employee " +
            "SET status = :status  where employeeId::text = :employeeId", nativeQuery = true)
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    void updateROGS(@Param("status") String status, @Param("employeeId") String employeeId);
```